# Appendix package ToC control

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, appendices

I want to change the alignment of the appendices. I'm using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
...
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toc,titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\uppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\uppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\uppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-3em}

\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\uppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-3em}
```

I'm having to modify a couple other things. 
This is what I have.

```
APPENDICES................. 10
APPENDIX A ................ 13
APPENDIX B ................ 15
```

This is what I need.

```
APPENDICES................. 10
   APPENDIX A ............. 13
   APPENDIX B ............. 15
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: report. I'm editing to include more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use `\titlecontents` from the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package.

### Remarks:

- Notice that the `titletoc` option for the `appendix` package is no longer needed.
- `\uppercase` is a TeX command that shouldn't be used in LaTeX documents; one can use `\MakeUppercase` instead; however, both these commands receive an argument, so the use of `\uppercase` (or `\MakeUppercase`) as it was being done in the example provided in the question will produce errors.
- Notice also that some of the original settings were replaced for some redefinitions and patches in my answer; in particular, I used a redefinition of `\l@chapter` to use the dotted leaders and to style the chapter entries using upper case. The internal commands `\@cftmaketoctitle`, `\@cftmakeloftitle`, and `\@cftmakelottitle` from `tocloft` were patched (with the help of the `etoolbox` package) to use upper case fonts for the titles of the ToC, LoF, and LoT, respectively.

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{textcase}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \MakeTextUppercase{#1}\nobreak\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill
\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\patchcmd{\@cftmaketoctitle}{\cfttoctitlefont\contentsname}{\cfttoctitlefont\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@cftmakeloftitle}{\cftloftitlefont\listfigurename}{\cftloftitlefont\MakeUppercase{\listfigurename}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@cftmakelottitle}{\cftlottitlefont\listtablename}{\cftlottitlefont\MakeUppercase{\listtablename}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}
%
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-3em}
%
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-3em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Regular Chapter}
\begin{appendices}
\titlecontents{chapter}[10em]
  {\addvspace{10pt}}
  {\contentslabel[\MakeUppercase{\appendixname~\thecontentslabel}]{8em}\MakeUppercase}
  {\hspace*{-8em}}{\titlerule*[.754em]{.}\contentspage}
\chapter{First Test Appendix}
\chapter{Second Test Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a final remark, (and just as a suggestion), I think that it would be better to use small capitals instead of upper case fonts for the entries in the ToC; this would also have an additional advantage: the implementation would be considerably easier.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using the report document class. This doesn't quite work. I'll play with it and see what I can come up with. Thanks

Comment: @Jeremiah I've updated my answer. Please take into account the remarks.

Comment: Sorry I disappeared, family. This works great!!

Comment: @Jeremiah No problem. So, you need, at some point in your document, to revert to the standard style for the chapter ToC entries (no upper case, boldfaced, dotless entries)?

Comment: Thanks, I edited that remark out when I figured it out. For the record @Gonzalo was answering this question - I need to revert back to the previous style.